# Percentage used in the Makefile rule that aims at renaming all .c files

Tags: makefile

I think percentage in Makefile means wildcard. As a try, I test a contrive Makefile that aims at changing any .c file to 'hi'.  This is my Makefile rule:

```
%.c:
         mv $@ hi
```

I save the file above to 'Makefile', and then type in the terminal

```
touch hello.c
make
```

The terminal says

```
make: `hello.c' is up to date.
```

which is certainly not what I wanted. Two naive questions:

- a) Why does makefile determine that 'hello.c' is actually "up to date"?
- b) How can we enforce the rule to be applied anyway?

Comment: it does not depend on anything

Comment: a target like 'clean' does not depend on anything neither. Any difference? Maybe do you mean "because it depends on nothing, it is always recent"?

Comment: You are right. I have to give full explanation. Please wait for my detailed response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined any dependencies in your rule. The `hello.c` already exists and none of the dependencies have newer timestamp than `hello.c`.

There are rules with no dependencies like `clean`. In this case the file `clean` does not exist and `make` tries to create it by executing the rule's set of commands. However, as mentioned in GNU make [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) this will not work in the case where `clean` file is created. The solution on this is to define `clean` as "Phony Target".

Additionally the output of the command is file `hi` and not `%.c`

The `Makefile` should look like:

```
%.hi : %.c
     mv $< $@
```

Comment: You should mention the `.PHONY` directive and why it is used (and necessary) for proper operation of targets like `clean`.